# How do I return the middle number in Haskell

Tags: haskell, int, guard

I have the following beginning of a function, and am unsure as to how I should return Middle Number (i.e. the number that is neither the largest nor smallest):

```
middleNumber :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
middleNumber a b c
    | ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you break the function into two steps: First, sort the three numbers. Then, take the middle element. For the first step, also consider if you can take it one step at a time; each step bringing it a bit closer to being fully sorted, then tail-recursing back to bring it even closer.

Answer (score 4):

The "middle number" is larger than one of the numbers, but smaller than the other number. And there is only one middle number. The most mechanical way to solve this would be to start off

```
middleNumber a b c
    | a < b && a > c = a
```

Check if `a` is the middle number by being less than `b` but greater than `c`.

Now what if `a` is the middle number, but it's actually *greater* than `b` and *less* than `c`? There's another guard. What if `b` is the middle number? There's another 2 guards. What if `c` is the middle number? There's 2 more guards, for a total of 6 different cases.

(btw, the expression `| a < b && a > c = a` is referred to as a guard. If you don't have a firm grasp yet of what guards are, then I recommend [LYAH # Guards](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards))

Of course there are better ways to write the function, but for understanding purposes it's good to be able to manually and systematically break down all of the possible situations, and determine what to do in each situation. [How To Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org/) is a great book for learning how to be systematic in this way.

Answer (score 3):

The obligatory Rube-Goldberg-answer:

```
import Control.Applicative

middleNumber a b c = sum $ [sum, negate.minimum, negate.maximum] <*> [[a,b,c]]
```

**[Edit]**

Here is another version:

```
middleNumber a b c = fst $ maximumBy (compare `on` abs.snd) [(a,b-c),(b,c-a),(c,a-b)]
```

I'm sure we could translate this to arrow syntax for further obfuscation, but I leave that task to the interested reader.

Comment: import Data.List ; middleNumber a b c = (sort [a,b,c]) !! 1

Comment: `let l = [a,b,c] in delete (minimum l) . delete (maximum l) $ l` ... :-)

Comment: another: `middleNumber a b c = minimum [max a b, max a c, max b c]` (the inverse also works)

Comment: @all: Nice! I think playing around is a good way to get a better feeling for the language, and textbook answers are just boring.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Dan Burton's answer with guards, I evaluate a, b, c cases each in its own guard. However, what happens when 2 of the numbers are equal? Then the middle number should be one of the duplicated ones.

```
middleNumber :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
middleNumber a b c
    | (a > b && a < c) || (a > c && a < b) = a
    | (b > a && b < c) || (b > c && b < a) = b
    | (c > a && c < b) || (c > b && c < a) = c
    | otherwise = if a == b then a else c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage guards and `where` to obtain the same result in simple way:

```hs
middleNumber :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
middleNumber x y z
  | a == x = max y z
  | a == y = max x z
  | a == z = max x y
  where
    a = max x $ max y z
```

If you don't have access to the built-in `max`. you can easily write your own.

```hs
max' :: Int -> Int -> Int
max' x y
  | x > y = x
  | otherwise = y
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick brute force method but this is **most certainly** not the best solution

```
import Data.List
middleNum :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
middleNum a b c = (\[_,m,_] -> m) $ sort $ a:b:c:[]
```

Obviously this is an awful idea as it explicitly relies on there being 3 items in the list, but it does the job